# Unity: tell container to always use specific implementation of an interface when registering a type

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I keep running into this scenario: suppose I have interface `IFoo` and several implementations, like `RedFoo : IFoo` and `BlackFoo : IFoo`. I then have classes that take `IFoo` in the constructor:

```
class BlackFooUser
{
   public BlackFooUser(IFoo foo, other_parameters_here) {...}
}

class RedFooUser
{
   public RedFooUser(IFoo foo, other_parameters_here) {...}
}
```

How do I tell the container to resolve all other parameters as usual, but always use `BlackFoo` when constructing `BlackFooUser`, and always use `RedFoo` when constructing `RedFooUser`? I know I can use `ParameterOverride` when calling `Resolve()`, but I want it to be the same whenever a `Red/BlackFooUser` is resolved, so this should go into `RegisterType` or `RegisterFactory`.

I can do something like

```
container.RegisterFactory<RedFooUser>(c=>new RedFooUser(c.Resolve<RedFoo>(), other_parameters_here));
```

but this is quite verbose, and this will have to change every time I add new parameters.

Is there a better way?

**UPDATE** I am specifically looking to do this through container registrations, without modifying the classes involved. There are multiple reasons for that, but it boils down to this:

- Encoding dependency information in the classes violates separation of concerns
- It usually scales poorly in case of many classes and many dependencies
- It puts limits to how the classes can be composed
- It restricts me to classes that I own the source to and can modify at will

Comment: Presumably you meant to tag this [tag:unity-container] not [tag:unity3d]?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I just tagged it as "unity". The thought of a clash with Unity3D crossed my mind briefly, but then I ignored it :) Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/unitycontainer/abstractions/issues/121) to UnityContainer repo, and the response by Eugene Sadovoy pushed me towards this answer.

To avoid an infinite loop, one can register the default factory as named registration, and invoke it from the default, unnamed factory, along the lines of (sorry, I changed the names a little compared to the question):

```
container
  .RegisterType<SpecialFooUser>("stdreg")
  .RegisterFactory<SpecialFooUser>(
      c => c.Resolve<SpecialFooUser>("stdreg", 
        new DependencyOverride<IFoo>(c.Resolve<SpecialFoo>()))
    );
```

This works, but looks quite verbose, so I wrote a few extension methods and classes (~100 lines of code total) to make it less verbose and more expressive:

```
container.Register(
  new CustomFactory<SpecialFooUser>()
    .DependencyOverride<IFoo, SpecialFoo>());
```

The complete source code is on GitHub: https://github.com/ikriv-samples/UnityResolveOverrideFactory

Answer (score 0):

Use an abstract class and generics to force a specific type.

Unity will automatically resolve a concrete type, so you don't need to register these.

```
public abstract class FooUser<TFoo> where TFoo : IFoo
{
    private readonly TFoo _foo;
    public FooUser(TFoo foo, other parameters)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }
}

public class BlackFooUser : FooUser<BlackFoo>
{
    public BlackFooUser (BlackFoo foo, other parameters)
        : base(foo, other parameters)
    {
    }
}

public class RedFooUser : FooUser<RedFoo>
{
    public RedFooUser (RedFoo foo, other parameters)
        : base(foo, other parameters)
    {
    }
}
```

Full reproduction below - output is:

> Constructed RedFooUser with foo 'RedFoo' and otherParameter 'I'm the other parameter'
>   Constructed BlackFooUser with foo 'BlackFoo' and otherParameter 'I'm the other parameter'

```
void Main()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer()
        .RegisterInstance<string>("I'm the other parameter");

    var foo1 = container.Resolve<RedFooUser>();
    var foo2 = container.Resolve<BlackFooUser>();

}

// Define other methods, classes and n
public interface IFoo 
{
}
public class BlackFoo : IFoo { }
public class RedFoo : IFoo { }

public abstract class FooUser<TFoo> where TFoo : IFoo
{

    private readonly TFoo _foo;
    public FooUser(TFoo foo, string otherParameter)
    {
        _foo = foo;
        Console.WriteLine($"Constructed {GetType().Name} with foo '{foo.GetType().Name}' and otherParameter '{otherParameter}'");
    }
}

public class BlackFooUser : FooUser<BlackFoo>
{
    public BlackFooUser(BlackFoo foo, string otherParameter)
        : base(foo, otherParameter)
    {
    }
}

public class RedFooUser : FooUser<RedFoo>
{
    public RedFooUser(RedFoo foo, string otherParameter)
        : base(foo, otherParameter)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I see a couple of problems with it. First, RedFooUser and BlackFooUser don't really care what implemenation of IFoo to take. It is purely an artifact of composition. Second, this works OK for one templated parameter, but if there are 3 or 4 (IFoo, IBar, IBaz), the number of permutations becomes prohibitive. And third, I still need to repeat the parameter list in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

When you register your types, you can give them a name, and then refer to that name in the constructors where those types get injected. Something like this:

```
public class BlackFoo : IFoo
{
    public const string UNITY_KEY = "BlackFoo";
}
```

In your container registration:

```
_container.RegisterType<IFoo, BlackFoo>(BlackFoo.UNITY_KEY, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

In your constructor:

```
public class BlackFooUser
{
    public BlackFooUser([Dependency(BlackFoo.UNITY_KEY)] IFoo foo)
    {
    }
}
```

This ensures that when the container does the dependency injection, it will use the named `IFoo` registration.

Comment: yes, I am aware of this feature. There are a few things I don't like about it: 1) The classes ideally should not decide what concrete dependencies they take 2) The dependency is now effectively fixed if I am using a container 3) I am not sure how it would work in more complicate scenarios where I want Func<IFoo>, or IFoo is resolved in multiple places in the hierarchy. I want to tell the container "IFoo means BlackFoo when resolving this type", and I want to tell it externally to the type, just like I do when there is only one implementation of IFoo

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov `BlackFooUser` doesn't actually know what it's getting. All it knows is that it wants an `IFoo` instance with a given name. I could register a `RedFoo` with the wrong key if I want. True, this does tightly couple the class to the key. But I'm not sure I totally understand what the issue is. In your question, you wanted to ensure that `BlackFooUser` gets `BlackFoo`, but in the comment to the other answer, you say that it doesn't really care which `IFoo` it gets. Can you explain this more clearly?

Comment: The idea of IoC as I understand it is that the classes don't make any composition decisions. All such decisions are done through the container registrations. I can do it easily with one implementation of IFoo, and I should be able to do it with two or more. Any proposal that modifies the classes violates this principle, and creates all kinds of problems at the large scale. I may not own the class source code to add the attribute, a named key for every dependency of every class is difficult to track, I may want the class to use Black in this program, but Red in another, etc.

Comment: Another tactic you can try is using child containers. Types registered in the children look in the same child container first for DI, and then in the parent if not found. So create a child container, register `BlackFooUser` and `BlackFoo` there, with the rest of the dependencies in the parent.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about this solution. The problem is, this is another workaround that does not scale. Handling multiple containers is a pain, and you would silently get a wrong thing if you use a wrong container, leading to hard to find bugs. Also, what if something depends on BOTH RedUser and BlackUser? A factory with an explicit 'new', bad as it is, is definitely better than this.  I am starting to get a feeling that what I am asking is not really possible in current Unity :)